# Python kivy: Can't pass data in on_press

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm a starting kivy I have a little problem. I want to call a function with "on_press", but data passed are the same.
If the last record in the database are "Stack" every on_press button will return "Stack" and bypass other string.

I need help

```
    try:
        conn = BddConnection.start()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        product = cursor.execute("""SELECT * from produits """)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            self.manager.ids.test.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(row[0]), size_hint_x=.1))
            self.manager.ids.test.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(row[1]), size_hint_x=.2))
            self.manager.ids.test.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(row[3]), size_hint_x=.2))
            self.manager.ids.test.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text=str(row[4]), size_hint_x=.1))
            self.manager.ids.test.ids.grid.add_widget(Button(text=str("Voir l'url"), value=row[2], size_hint_x=.1, on_release=lambda x:self.popup(row[1]), size_hint=(0.0, 0.3)))

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Pas de produit : {}".format(error))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is explained in the python [Programming FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3.6/faq/programming.html?highlight=lambda#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result). I believe it can be fixed by changing the 'on_release' for your `Button` to:

```
on_release=lambda x, n=row[1]: self.popup(n)
```

as described in the above link.